# Convert date in INT to DateTime for CreateEvent of Google Calendar API

Tags: google-bigquery, google-calendar-api

Calendar API CreateEvent  [Event created](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/calendar#create_event) response has a parameter called end_time  that returns an integer, any idea how to convert this integer to date-time?

if you help me with BigQuery SQL will be much more appreciated

One of the values is, for instance: 63714621600

After writing it into the database I was trying to query it in BigQuery, but it is not giving me the right date_time SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST(end_time AS INT64)*1000) FROM `xxxx.xxxx.Calendar` but it gives me a 1972 datetime.

Thank you.

Comment: try https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: can you provide few other examples of values in data?

Comment: SELECT time, start_time, end_time FROM `xxx.TestData.Calendar` LIMIT 10

Row time start_time end_time 
1 
2020-08-10T04:05:34.475Z
63732758400
63732762000
2 
2019-10-05T02:50:50.965Z
63705922200
63705925800
3 
2019-10-05T02:50:50.965Z
63705922200
63705925800
4 
2019-10-05T02:50:50.965Z
63705922200
63705925800
5 
2019-10-04T21:54:44.846Z
63705922200
63705925800
6 
2019-10-04T21:54:44.846Z
63705922200
63705925800
7 
2019-10-04T21:54:44.846Z
63705922200
63705925800
8 
2020-10-16T15:16:50.748Z
63738898200
63738900000

Comment: @DaImTo appraently it is not epoch. Try, for instance, 63705922200. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe these are seconds since 0001-01-01 AD:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP '0001-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 63732758400 SECOND)
```

[image]

Comment: Almost! it is returning one day after event.
2021-03-03 16:30:00 UTC instead of
2021-03-02 16:30:00 UTC
Thanks

Comment: I corrected it with SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP '0001-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 63732758400 - 86400 SECOND)

Not elegant, but functional